# Prevent GCC compiler from constant folding

Tags: disassembly, c, gcc

I have simple C Code:

```
int main() {
    int b = 3-1;
    return 0;
}
```

And when I objdump it after compiling with no optimization:

```
000000000000113d <main>:
    113d:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1141:       55                      push   rbp
    1142:       48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
    1145:       c7 45 fc 02 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x2
    114c:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
    1151:       5d                      pop    rbp
    1152:       c3                      ret
    1153:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nop    WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]
    115a:       00 00 00
    115d:       0f 1f 00                nop    DWORD PTR [rax]
```

We can clearly tell the compiler has simplified the expression 3-1=2 by line 1145. My goal is figure out where this is happening and to prevent this from happening.
I have read trough the options of https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html and figured out that by default we still have some optimization, but none of them are doing constant folding and -ftree-dominator-opts is disabled by default.

So where is this constant folding exactly happening?
And how can I avoid this from happening without modifying the source code?

Comment: AFAIK, without modifying the source code, there's no way to prevent constant folding in gcc or clang. Some reasoning (for clang) is given [here](https://discourse.llvm.org/t/constant-folding-in-clang/26840/5). What are you trying to accomplish? If you want each constant to be stored onto the stack before it's used in the expression, you can use local variables.

Comment: Working on a project, reverse engineering with AI, where the model learns the seq2seq translation. I try to keep C Code and Assembly literal representations consistent in HEX format, so the model does not need to learn approximate the translation for which we have explicit functions. I thought about translating all literals to HEX manually. Problem is the constant folding. I either try to get my C code in intermediate folded version, or I prevent folding was my thought. Your link looks useful.

Comment: If the C input is going to be relatively simple, you could do the folding yourself via a script (or a compiler front-end pass) and replace the equations with the calculated values in the C file. It's hard to say without knowing more, but using IR instead of C may also suit you more well, since correspondence between IR and machine code will be much closer than C vs machine code. You could then lift the produced IR to C outside of your model.